# Gson to parse string of arrays

Tags: java, json, gson

I need to parse the below JSON content. Currently I have stored it inflat file and reading it. I have given the sample POJO classes which are created and the code which I tried below.

Tried two different approach and both are giving the following error

`Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 3 path $`

Json file

---

```
{
    "DeviceCommon": {
        "ASIdentifier": "123",
        "DatadeliveyMechanism": "notify",
        "MobileOriginatorCallbackReference": {
            "url": "http://application.example.com/inbound/notifications/modatanotification/"
        },
        "AccessiblityCallbackReference": {
            "url": "http://application.example.com/inbound/notifications/accessibilitystatusnotification"
        }
    },
    "DeviceList": [{
        "ExternalIdentifer": "123456@mydomain.com",
        "msisdn": "123456",
        "senderName": "Device1",
        "MobileOriginatorCallbackReference": {
            "notifyURL": "http://application.example.com/inbound/notifications/modatanotification/"
        },
        "ConfigurationResultCallbackReference": {
            "notifyURL": "http://application.example.com/inbound/notifications/configurationResult"
        },
        "ASreferenceID": "AS000001",
        "NIDDduration": "1d"
    }]
}
```

POJO classes:
Note: I have mentioned only two classes here.

```
package com.As.jsonmodel.configrequest;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)

public class ConfigurationRequest
{
    private DeviceList[] DeviceList;

    private DeviceCommon DeviceCommon;

    public DeviceList[] getDeviceList ()
    {
        return DeviceList;
    }

    public void setDeviceList (DeviceList[] DeviceList)
    {
        this.DeviceList = DeviceList;
    }

    public DeviceCommon getDeviceCommon ()
    {
        return DeviceCommon;
    }

    public void setDeviceCommon (DeviceCommon DeviceCommon)
    {
        this.DeviceCommon = DeviceCommon;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [DeviceList = "+DeviceList+", DeviceCommon = "+DeviceCommon+"]";
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.As.jsonmodel.configrequest;


public class DeviceList
{
    private MobileOriginatorCallbackReference MobileOriginatorCallbackReference;

    private String NIDDduration;

    private String ASreferenceID;

    private String senderName;

    private String ExternalIdentifer;

    private String msisdn;

    private ConfigurationResultCallbackReference ConfigurationResultCallbackReference;

    public MobileOriginatorCallbackReference getMobileOriginatorCallbackReference ()
    {
        return MobileOriginatorCallbackReference;
    }

    public void setMobileOriginatorCallbackReference (MobileOriginatorCallbackReference MobileOriginatorCallbackReference)
    {
        this.MobileOriginatorCallbackReference = MobileOriginatorCallbackReference;
    }

    public String getNIDDduration ()
    {
        return NIDDduration;
    }

    public void setNIDDduration (String NIDDduration)
    {
        this.NIDDduration = NIDDduration;
    }

    public String getASreferenceID ()
    {
        return ASreferenceID;
    }

    public void setASreferenceID (String ASreferenceID)
    {
        this.ASreferenceID = ASreferenceID;
    }

    public String getSenderName ()
    {
        return senderName;
    }

    public void setSenderName (String senderName)
    {
        this.senderName = senderName;
    }

    public String getExternalIdentifer ()
    {
        return ExternalIdentifer;
    }

    public void setExternalIdentifer (String ExternalIdentifer)
    {
        this.ExternalIdentifer = ExternalIdentifer;
    }

    public String getMsisdn ()
    {
        return msisdn;
    }

    public void setMsisdn (String msisdn)
    {
        this.msisdn = msisdn;
    }

    public ConfigurationResultCallbackReference getConfigurationResultCallbackReference ()
    {
        return ConfigurationResultCallbackReference;
    }

    public void setConfigurationResultCallbackReference (ConfigurationResultCallbackReference ConfigurationResultCallbackReference)
    {
        this.ConfigurationResultCallbackReference = ConfigurationResultCallbackReference;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [MobileOriginatorCallbackReference = "+MobileOriginatorCallbackReference+", NIDD duration = "+NIDDduration+", AS referenceID = "+ASreferenceID+", senderName = "+senderName+", ExternalIdentifer = "+ExternalIdentifer+", msisdn = "+msisdn+", ConfigurationResultCallbackReference = "+ConfigurationResultCallbackReference+"]";
    }
}
```

---

Json Reader
Approach1:

```
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(  
                     new FileReader("/home/raj/apache-tomcat-8.0.3/webapps/file.json"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
        JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new FileReader("/home/raj/apache-tomcat-8.0.3/webapps/file.json"));

        jsonReader.beginObject();

        while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {

        String name = jsonReader.nextName();
            if (name.equals("DeviceCommon")) {
                 readApp(jsonReader);

            }
        }

        jsonReader.endObject();
        jsonReader.close();
    }

    public static void readApp(JsonReader jsonReader) throws IOException{
        jsonReader.beginObject();
         while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {
             String name = jsonReader.nextName();
             System.out.println(name);
             if (name.contains("ASIdentifier")){
                 jsonReader.beginObject();
                 while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {
                     String n = jsonReader.nextName();
                     if (n.equals("MobileOriginatorCallbackReference")){
                         System.out.println(jsonReader.nextString());
                     }
                     if (n.equals("AccessiblityCallbackReference")){
                         System.out.println(jsonReader.nextInt());
                     }
                     if (n.equals("DeviceList")){
                         jsonReader.beginArray();
                         while  (jsonReader.hasNext()) {
                              System.out.println(jsonReader.nextString());
                         }
                         jsonReader.endArray();
                     }
                 }
                 jsonReader.endObject();
             }

         }
         jsonReader.endObject();
    }


    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
```

Aproach2:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
DeviceList [] myTypes = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("/home/raj/apache-tomcat-8.0.3/webapps/file.json"), DeviceList[].class);
System.out.println(gson.toJson(myTypes));
```

Any pointers on how to parse this file will be helpful.

Comment: You could seriously just consider using **http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/** copy the JSON in and you literally get the classes that GSON parses this file into (just make sure you set it to `JSON` as input format, and `GSON` as library)

Comment: `DeviceList [] myTypes = gson.fromJson(.../file.json)` from what we see your JSON doesn't hold array, but object which holds array. Use `ConfigurationRequest cr = gson.fromJson(.../file.json)` and then from returned object get array you want `cr.getDeviceList()`.

Comment: why do you use `DeviceList[]` type instead of `ConfigurationRequest`??

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it with Gson:

```java
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Data data = new Gson().fromJson(new FileReader("data.json"), Data.class);
        System.out.println(data);
    }
}

class Data {

    @SerializedName("DeviceCommon")
    DeviceCommon deviceCommon;

    @SerializedName("DeviceList")
    DeviceListEntry[] deviceList;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Data{" +
                "\n  deviceCommon=" + deviceCommon +
                "\n  deviceList=" + Arrays.toString(deviceList) +
                "\n}";
    }
}

class DeviceCommon {

    @SerializedName("ASIdentifier")
    String asIdentifier;

    @SerializedName("DatadeliveyMechanism")
    String datadeliveyMechanism;

    @SerializedName("MobileOriginatorCallbackReference")
    Url mobileOriginatorCallbackReference;

    @SerializedName("AccessiblityCallbackReference")
    Url accessiblityCallbackReference;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DeviceCommon{" +
                "\n    asIdentifier='" + asIdentifier + '\'' +
                "\n    datadeliveyMechanism='" + datadeliveyMechanism + '\'' +
                "\n    mobileOriginatorCallbackReference=" + mobileOriginatorCallbackReference +
                "\n    accessiblityCallbackReference=" + accessiblityCallbackReference +
                "\n  }";
    }
}

class DeviceListEntry {

    @SerializedName("ExternalIdentifer")
    String externalIdentifer;

    String msisdn;

    String senderName;

    @SerializedName("MobileOriginatorCallbackReference")
    NotifyUrl mobileOriginatorCallbackReference;

    @SerializedName("ConfigurationResultCallbackReference")
    NotifyUrl configurationResultCallbackReference;

    @SerializedName("ASreferenceID")
    String asReferenceID;

    @SerializedName("NIDDduration")
    String nidDduration;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DeviceListEntry{" +
                "\n    externalIdentifer='" + externalIdentifer + '\'' +
                "\n    msisdn='" + msisdn + '\'' +
                "\n    senderName='" + senderName + '\'' +
                "\n    mobileOriginatorCallbackReference=" + mobileOriginatorCallbackReference +
                "\n    configurationResultCallbackReference=" + configurationResultCallbackReference +
                "\n    asReferenceID='" + asReferenceID + '\'' +
                "\n    nidDduration='" + nidDduration + '\'' +
                "\n  }";
    }
}

class Url {

    String url;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return url;
    }
}

class NotifyUrl {

    String notifyURL;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return notifyURL;
    }
}
```

Running `Main` will result in the following output:

```
Data{
  deviceCommon=DeviceCommon{
    asIdentifier='123'
    datadeliveyMechanism='notify'
    mobileOriginatorCallbackReference=http://application.example.com/inbound/notifications/modatanotification/
    accessiblityCallbackReference=http://application.example.com/inbound/notifications/accessibilitystatusnotification
  }
  deviceList=[DeviceListEntry{
    externalIdentifer='123456@mydomain.com'
    msisdn='123456'
    senderName='Device1'
    mobileOriginatorCallbackReference=http://application.example.com/inbound/notifications/modatanotification/
    configurationResultCallbackReference=http://application.example.com/inbound/notifications/configurationResult
    asReferenceID='AS000001'
    nidDduration='1d'
  }]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It helped a lot. Couple of more questions  .               1.  How do I get the particular filed.(e.g misdn) from data class?                      2. Instead of reading it file, how can I get it from http request. The idea here is user sends this JSON data to REST server.(post) method,I need to directly read the content from HTTP and call gson from Json.

Comment: @ramkriz you get specific fields by creating methods for them. I recommend you create new questions here on SO for any remaining issues you have. These comment boxes are not well suited for Q&A's.